# C program problems code not working

Tags: c, scanf

I am more versed with c# than i am c and i am having a problem with a program i am trying to write to calculate good Friday.

Thanks for all the help its working now sorry most of it was stupid stuff i should have known.

```
int main(void)
{
    /*variables I will be using*/
    int year;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;

    /*what will the computer print first*/
    printf("Welcome to the Good Friday Computing Program!\n Please enter\n a year between 1982 and 2048: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);




    /*determine if yeat is with in 1982 and 2048*/
    if ( year >=  1982)
    {
        if (year >= 2048)
        {
            printf("Enter year from 1982 to 2048");
        }
        else
        {
            /*computing good friday*/
            a = year % 19;
            b = year % 4;
            c = year % 7;
            d = (19 * a + 24) % 30;
            e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5) % 7;
            f = d + e;

            /* determine if march or april */
            if (f > 11) 
            {
                printf("Good Friday in %d is April %d", year, f - 11); 
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Good Friday in %d is March %d", year, f + 20);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter year from 1982 to 2048");
    }

    /*keeps window open*/
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `19 & a` --> `19*a`, also other `&` to `*`

Comment: guess i should have known that. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
scanf("%y", &year);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &year);
```

`%d` implies integer

You are still getting error because you need to change in 2 more places

```
        if (f > 11)
        {
            printf("Good Friday in %d is April %d", year, f + 20);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Good Friday in %d is March %d", year, f + 20);
        }
```

Comment: still just exits after entering year.

Comment: updated answer. please make changes and build again.

Comment: edited the build works great from your origanal answer just needed getchar(); at the end to keep it open. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues on:

1. `scanf("%y")` which should be `scanf("%d")`
2. `printf("%y")` which should be `printf("%d")`
3. as already said - `&` is `*`.

That's a bommer.

Answer (score -1):

as for keeping the window open

```
getchar();
getchar();
```

causes it to stay open